# Unable check out the code from svn

Tags: svn

I'm unable to check out the code from SVN.
It's stopping at a big file of size 46 mb, and I got this error:

```
C:/Projects/Nucleus/branches/src/com/vattikutiirf/nucleus/ui/server/reports/fonts
 >
Error while performing action: REPORT request failed on
'/svn/nucleus/!svn/vcc/default'
 REPORT of '/svn/nucleus/!svn/vcc/default': Could not read response body:
 connection was closed by server. (http://122.181.129.237)
```

Can anyone suggest how to overcome this problem?

Comment: You have a 46Mb font? :( Just sayin'

Comment: Which SVN client are you using?

Comment: looks like connection/VPN drops. SVN seems innocent here.

Answer (score 1):

Both threads ([this one](http://www.mail-archive.com/osg-users@lists.openscenegraph.org/msg30459.html) or [that one](http://subversion.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1065&dsMessageId=2412258)) reports some timeout issue on the server side (Apache httpd).

The usual troubleshooting is to:

- look at the error.log apache file on the server
- see if there is any core config setting you can tweak on the server to increase the timeout period (like the [`keepalivetimeout` setting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#keepalivetimeout)).